# Why are there two extra calls to destructor as I have created only two objects and using overloaded assignment operator and increment operator

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class loc{

    int iVAL;

public:

    loc(int i){
        cout<<"inside parameter constructor"<<endl;
        iVAL = i;
    }

    loc(){

        iVAL = 0;
        cout<<"inside default constructor"<<endl;
    }

    loc operator+(loc ob1){
        loc temp;
        temp.iVAL = iVAL + ob1.iVAL;
        return temp;
    }
    void show(){
        cout<<iVAL;
    }

    loc  operator++(){
        cout<<"inside pre increment"<<endl;
        ++iVAL;
        return *this;
    }

    loc operator++(int x){
        cout<<"inside post increment"<<endl;
        iVAL++;
        return *this;
    }

    loc operator=(loc &ob){
        cout<<"inside assignment"<<endl;
        iVAL = ob.iVAL;
        return *this;
    }

    ~loc(){
        cout<<this->iVAL<<endl;
        cout<<"inside loc destructor"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    loc ob1(10),ob3;

    ob3 = ++ob1;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

> inside parameter constructor
>   inside default constructor
>   inside pre increment
>   inside assignment
>   11
>   inside loc destructor  // extra call to destructor
>   11
>   inside loc destructor  // extra call to destructor
>   11
>   inside loc destructor
>   11
>   inside loc destructor

Comment: So... what do your assignment and increment operators **return** ? What do they take for parameters? Hm..... (post-inc return type is right btw, the *implementation* is wrong, however).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of

```
ob3 = ++ob1;
```

Look at this code more carefully

loc  operator++(){
       cout<<"inside pre incriment"<

So what can you do to avoid this extra copy.. You can return by reference

```
const loc&  operator++(){
   cout<<"inside pre incriment"<<endl;
   ++iVAL;
   return *this; <--- you create a new copy and send it back
}
```

The above code returns by reference and the const pointer is prevent others from modifying your value.

However the code you have written for pre increment is wrong
It should retun the value before increment.

So the code should be something like this

```
loc operator++(){
   cout<<"inside pre incriment"<<endl;
   int  temp = iVAL;
   ++iVAL;
   return temp; <--- you create a new copy and send it back
}
```

In this case you cannot return by reference between temp is a temporary variable.

Comment: The pre-increment operator should return `loc&` while the post-increment operator should return `const loc&` to minimize copying.

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention his post increment operator is wrong

Comment: pre-increment should return the updated value, and return by reference. Your last code block is bad

Comment: R Sahu - post-increment returns the previous value of the object being incremented, not a reference.